# Reactjs "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open.." after converting jsx file to tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I have a `create-react-app` app and I am translation files from `jsx` to `typescript`. For example, one file is called `/code/app_react/src/common/Action.jsx` and I renamed it to `/code/app_react/src/common/Action.tsx`. I made the necessary changes to successfully convert it to `tsx`, but I am getting an error related to the name change:

> ./src/common/Action.jsx Error: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, open
>   '/code/src/common/Action.jsx'

- rebuilding the does not help
- for some reason, the old version of the file is expected

The file importing this file is a `jsx` file, but now I am importing a `tsx` file into it.

This is a CRA app, so is there a correct way to clear this error?

**SOLUTION:**
I had to remove them from the `git` repository, using the `git rm` command, like this:

```
git rm /code/src/common/Action.jsx
```

Once I did that, it removed the `jsx` from the committed files and then I was able to use the new `tsx` files

Comment: did you import the file? `import Action from '/code/app_react/src/common/Action.tsx'`

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly fine when the extension is `jsx`

Comment: I have this issue as well. I'm importing the file without extension, and after an extension change I always get ENOENT and have to restart dev server. Very frustrating since that script is soooo slow to start. I will try to import with explicit extension after rename and see if that solves it.

Comment: @thehme Did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: yes, i had to run `git rm /code/src/common/Action.jsx`

Comment: Hi, please don't put the solution in the question. Provide an answer instead. @thehme

Answer (score 74):

Killed my yarn process running, killed vscode, re-started both and it works

Comment: how to kill yarn process? Is there any command for this? Finding for ubuntu

Comment: A simple server restart works...

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. After reloading VS code it displayed the tsconfig.json file & the issues were resolved.

Answer (score 16):

I had same issue, no need to remove `node_modules` or remove target file, you just have to kill the node process.

If you're on `windows`:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> to run task manager
- find `node`
- end process

If you're on `linux`:

- probably something like `pkill node`, etc.

After I killed the `node` process and ran `npm start` again, it finds the target file.

Answer (score 10):

I was having this problem (though I had renamed `js` to `jsx`, rather than `jsx` to `tsx`), and the solution added to the question (running `git rm` on the original file) didn't work for me.

What did work was suggested by [this r/reactjs Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/95e9cc/how_can_i_use_js_instead_of_jsx/e3s160u): deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm i
```

Answer (score 7):

It is happening because of the pre-built cache. A simple solution would be to restart your nodejs and react app.

**In Linux**

```
$ pkill node   

$ killall node  

$ kill -9 <pid>
```

**In Windows**

```
C:\>taskkill /im node.exe

C:\>taskkill /f /im node.exe

C:\>taskkill /pid <PID of node>
```

**In MacOs**

```
$sudo killall -9 node
```

And then start your React application again.

```
npm start
```

Comment: Do we really need to restart `react-scripts` everytime we remove or move a file? I am tired of waiting 1 minute for `react-scripts` to boot up and compile my project :/

Comment: Not need to every time but if you have cache issue, sometimes restarting and cache invalidation would help.

Comment: restarting the server solved my issue, as simple as that

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have not imported the file. You need to import the file to use it.

```
import Action from '/code/app_react/src/common/Action.tsx';
```

Also add this to your webpack.config.js.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
},
```

You're good to go!

Comment: There is no `webpack.config.js` in an app created with `create-react-app`. Unless you eject or use react-rewired or some such tool.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue converting .jsx to .tsx. If you're using Parcel to build your app, delete the `.cache` folder. That's where Parcel caches build files. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

npm run build

try running this command

After giving npm start I was getting this error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\React\client.next\BUILD_ID']

Try rebuilding your Next.js project. You can do this by running the following command from your project's root directory:
npm run build

This fixed my error and after giving npm start everything is working fine

Answer (score 1):

I was working with redux and then came across this error!!

I tried killing node , removing node modules, restarting the laptop but it still gave the same error then later I started debugging index.js

I commented each line and started uncommenting from top to see where the code is breaking then observed

> I had not installed
>
> redux
>
> I had only installed react-redux

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your npm server, it will automatically detect the typescript file and make adjustments

Answer (score 1):

It took me all day and all I needed was to restart docker :)
And I do need to restart it after every file change to tsx.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in parent folder or other folder not current folder then you got this error.
Just go that directory, by using command

```
cd folder-name 
npm start
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

I manually deleted the `node_modules` folder and re-installed them by running `npm i` and the trick worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple server restart works.

Eg: NPM RUN DEV or any start script worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem in a React Application (started with yarn start and displayed at localhost:3000). The problem arised after renaming a component and forgetting the suffix .js. After adding the suffix .js the already started App still was searching for the file without the suffix. The solution was similar to Umanda's recommendation:

Ctrl-C

yarn start

Then the App worked.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem when I try to run my next js apps, to fix this I just delete `.next` folder that contains cache files and it works!

I think for `create-react-app` you need to restart the server